# Is it correct to say "could you turn the songs/ videos on"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Your wife is holding a mobile phone which contains many songs/videos in song/video formats such as mp3 or avi.

In [dictionaries](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/turn-on), "**turn on/ off**" is often used for machines.

> to make a machine or piece of electrical equipment such as a
> television, engine, light etc start operating by **pushing a button**,
> turning a key etc
>
> Eg, "*Jake turned on his computer and checked his mail.*"

The dictionary says "**by pushing a button**". We also **push a button** on an app, on a mobiephone for example, to **turn on** a song / video.

Is it idiomatic to say "**could you turn the songs/ videos on**"?

It seems that people say "**play**", "**could you play the song/video**?". But I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think 'turn on' is a little unnatural but you could use 'put on' instead. Of course, 'play' is also correct.

> Can you put on that song we heard earlier?   (<strike>turn on</strike>)
> Could you play the video from timestamp 12:32?  (<strike>turn on</strike>)
> I'm going to put on some videos about travel. (<strike>turn on</strike>)